# Outlook Calendar Trigger Excel Workbook Open

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am looking for VBA code to trigger when an outlook schedule reminder opens and for it to then open an excel wookbook. I was using the below code from another question/answer however I keep getting a

> "Type Mismatch" error

that is showing up on line "GetTemp Item". Would anyone have a solution for me?

[image]

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then

        If Not Item.Subject = "US SANCTION REPORT RUN" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

    GetTemp Item ' call sub
End Sub

Private Sub GetTemp(ByVal Item As TaskItem)
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hha106\Desktop\RUN US SANCTION REPORT.xlsm") ' update with Excel name
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the variable `Item` you submit here `GetTemp Item` is not the same type as declared here `GetTemp(ByVal Item As TaskItem)`.

Try `Private Sub GetTemp(ByVal Item As Outlook.TaskItem)`.

Also I don't get why you have `Item` as parameter of your `GetTemp` procedure because it is never used in `GetTemp`. So `Private Sub GetTemp()` and then calling `GetTemp` without `Item` should work too.

---

But the main issue is that if this statement

```
If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then
```

is not `True` then it will jump to  `End If` and proceed with running `GetTemp Item`. So you would need to put that before the `End If`, so it only runs `GetTemp` if `Item` actually is a `TaskItem`. Otherwise it would run on any other items that are not `TaskItem` too.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then

        If Not Item.Subject = "US SANCTION REPORT RUN" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        GetTemp Item ' call sub
    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PEH, I have added your ideas however I am now getting a "Sytax Error" with the below code (GetTemp is showing up in red also):
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then
        If Not Item.Subject = "US SANCTION REPORT RUN" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        GetTemp(ByVal Item As Outlook.TaskItem)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub GetTemp(ByVal Item As TaskItem)
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

etc.

Comment: @hwaterboy your call to `GetTemp Item` needs to stay as shown above. Only the sub needs the declaration `Private Sub GetTemp(ByVal Item As Outlook.TaskItem)`.

Comment: Got you. I changed this up and I am it won't trigger with the End If after the GetTemp as opposed to before. Although it runs with the End If before it still has the error at the GetTemp line.

Comment: That means that `If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then` is never true then. Go through your code step by step using F8 (also see [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)). I assume that `Item` is always of type `Object`. Replace it with `If TypeName(Item) = "TaskItem" Then` and see if that works. Otherwise check what the `TypeName(Item)` of your desired item is.